# can't get image name in cakephp edit.ctp file

Tags: cakephp

```
$image_name = $this->data['ApkCollection']['apk_image']['name'];
echo $image_name;   // it show result as number like 7 or 3 etc...
```

when am upload image in edit.ctp file means it show image name as above result, but it works fine on add.ctp file

Someone help me...

Comment: Please post the output of `debug($this->data['ApkCollection']['apk_image'])`. It would also help to see the logic that handles the file uploads.

Answer (score 0):

Is your code from the controller or view (edit.ctp)? If you're inspecting the posted data in the controller, what does this show?

```
pr($this->request->data['ApkCollection']['apk_image'])
```

If it's in the view, wouldn't it just be this?

```
$image_name = $this->data['ApkCollection']['apk_image'];
echo $image_name;
```

The file details array (that 'name' is part of) only exists as the result of a post, I think.

Toby

Comment: $image_name = $this->data['ApkCollection']['apk_image'];
echo $image_name;

Comment: Is this after a post though?